# Error Message when trying to use two \betas in subscript

Tags: subscripts

I am trying to use

```
$\simga_{\beta_1 \beta_2}$ and $\simga_{\beta_2 \beta_1}$
```

in my text. However, I always get the following error message, which I do not understand

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.266 ...ma_{\beta_1}^2,\sigma_{\beta_2}^2, \simga
_{\beta_1\beta_2}$ and $\s...
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You have `\simga` instead of `\sigma`.

General rule: at the end of the top part of the line with an error there is a reason of it. In this case `\simga`.

Comment: Has been a long time since I felt this stupid! Thanks alot. Do not know how I missed that.

Comment: @Mucteam don't worry, we've all don't it